# .sty of installed package not found

Tags: fonts, errors, packages, installing, texlive

I've newly installed TeXLive 2013 (following steps on http://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html) on Fedora 19.

Using `pdflatex` on a test `.tex`, I encounter lots of error messages saying various `.sty` were not found, beginning with `stmaryrd.sty`.

I checked with `tlmgr` and found the package is installed.
I checked the ctan for a manual install of `stmaryrd` and found the installing steps too briefly described for me, saying

> - move stmary*.tfm into a TeX font metrics directory
> - move stmary*.*pk into a TeX bitmaps directory

and I don't know which these directories are.

Being said, the file compiles fine on a different linux computer I used to work on, but I don't know about its setup.

Comment: is there some reason you don't want to install the tex live package for stmaryrd?  (those instructions don't even address the current state of the package, but it's orphaned ... no mother or father to tidy it up.)

Comment: Texlive manager tells me it IS installed, and I meant that I would indeed like to install it manually to see if it helps, but I don't know what the instructions mean.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a non reproducible problem